# Where is the appositive? "Each bottle had its own tight seal cork and wire."

Tags: appositives

Where is the appositive in this sentence?

> Each bottle had its own tight seal cork and wire.

Comment: There is no appositive modifier in your example. Compare "We went to see the opera Carmen", where the noun "Carmen" is an appositive modifier of the noun "opera".

Comment: It is likely that 'cork and wire' was meant to stand in apposition with 'tight seal' -- It would have been better with a comma after 'seal'.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> There is no appositive modifier in your example. Compare "We went to see the opera Carmen", where the noun "Carmen" is an appositive modifier of the noun "opera".

Answer (score 1):

As Aml said in a comment, there is supposed to be a comma after "seal":

> Each bottle had its own tight seal, cork and wire.

and the apposition/appositive is supposed to be "cork and wire". You can see the sentence given, with a comma and with "seal" circled and "cork and wine" underlined, in the following powerpoint: https://www.wtps.org/cms/lib/NJ01912980/Centricity/Domain/1135/nouns%207th%20grade.pptx

Comment: It would be a lot clearer (and, I'd say, normal) if the type of seal (an expansive rather than a restating appositive) were bracketed: Each bottle had its own tight seal (cork and wire).

Comment: Can we classify the absolute  'bruised and bloody' as an appositive in 'There stood the returning hero, bruised and bloody'? I'm happy with explanatory paraphrases of the same word class, such as 'She decided to impignorate (pawn) her necklace to pay his commission' being classed as appositives (though not all are).